# ERROR 2245: Cannot get schema from loadFunc org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hcatalog

I try to load files from a partitioned Hive table.

```
LKR_BU = LOAD 'baseName.tableName' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
```

After running I get the following error:

```
2016-07-04 15:01:58,743 [uber-SubtaskRunner] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt  - ERROR 2245: Cannot get schema from loadFunc org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader
```

For information, I have all the required libraries and HCatalog {Loader, Storer} works perfectly with oozie launcher.

Someone already encountered this kind of problem ?

Comment: Did you login with pig -useHCatalog ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many steps you need to follow to make HCatalog work in Pig.

Overall, I assume that you would have configured all the paths (hcatalog) and you would have included all the required jars in the classpath.

If not, please follow this post :- 
http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2013/11/InstallingAndConfiguringHCatalogAndIntegratingWithPig.html#comment-form

Or, you can also follow below post :-
https://acadgild.com/blog/loading-and-storing-hive-data-into-pig/

After you have followed all the steps above, you would need to start following services :-

- hiveserver2 --> hive --service hiveserver2
- hive metastore  -->  hive  --service metastore

After following above steps, definitely it would work as I was facing same issue and then I resolved it.

Hope it helps.